# matlab sort 2 columns: column 1 descending and column 2 ascending

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, vector

I have a 3 column array like this:

```
A = [6 -1 0;
     6  0 3;
     1  4 3;
     1  2 5];
```

I need the first column to be in descending order and the second column to be in ascending order with the third column changing with the other two columns (i.e. they are not sorted) like this:

```
B = [6 -1 0;
     6  0 3;
     1  2 5;
     1  4 3];
```

Comment: How the third column has changed?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear: should the rows remain intact (i.e. as in a multi-sort where the first sort is most important and then the second column shows a 'sub-sort'), or does the order of the entries in column 3 (and possible further columns) not matter?

Comment: I updated the post. The third column is not to be sorted as shown in the example array B.

Comment: In other words, are you trying to use the second column as a "tie-breaker" to order rows whose values are the same for column 1? The example data set is making things ambiguous, because sorting by column 2 ascending will also sort column 1 descending as a side effect, because of the selection of data items.

Comment: To clarify, what should the output be if the input is `A = [6 -1 0; 6 0 3; 1 4 5; 1 2 5; 7 5 4];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to keep the rows intact as records, and sort them based on column 1 and then column 2, use `sortrows()`, with negative column indexes to indicate columns whose values are to be sorted in descending order.

```
B = sortrows(A, [-1 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the third column is to be unchanged,

```
 B = A;
 B(:,1) = sort(B(:,1),'descend');
 B(:,2) = sort(B(:,2),'ascend');
```

If you want the third column to change with the second then,

```
[B(:,2),ind] = sort(B(:,2),'ascend');
B(:,3) = B(ind,3);

B =

 6    -1     0
 6     0     3
 1     2     5
 1     4     3
```

Comment: This will work if column A is actually independent from column B. But if this is actually about doing a multi-column sort on records, then this will fail because it changes the association of column A with rows. Since OP said the third column is to change "with the other two columns", sounds like this might be the case, and the choice of a degenerate input set is masking the problem.